# T-SQL MINUS operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, except

These are the tables I have created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(Customer_No INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Customer_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE DVD
(DVD_No INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 DVD_Name VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE DVD_Purchase
(DVD_Purchase_No INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 DVD_No INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Customer_No INTEGER NOT NULL
 )

INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES('Daman')
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES('Saif')
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES('Gurung')
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES('Upendra')
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES('Ornob')

INSERT INTO DVD (DVD_Name)
VALUES('Bleach')
INSERT INTO DVD (DVD_Name)
VALUES('Gintama')
INSERT INTO DVD (DVD_Name)
VALUES('Tokyo Ghoul')
INSERT INTO DVD (DVD_Name)
VALUES('Death Note')
INSERT INTO DVD (DVD_Name)
VALUES('Rurouni Kenshin')


INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (4,1)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (2,3)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (3,3)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (4,3)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (1,4)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (2,4)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (5,1)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (5,2)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (5,3)
INSERT INTO DVD_Purchase (DVD_No,Customer_No)
VALUES (5,4)
```

In order to display customer names who did not purchase any DVD by using MINUS operator, this is what I have tried:

```
SELECT Customer_Name
FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_No 
IN
(SELECT Customer_No FROM Customer
 MINUS
 SELECT Customer_No FROM DVD_Purchase
)
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 123 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'SELECT'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

As shown in the error message, Incorrect syntax near ')' which I'm unable to figure out.

Other than that, can someone provide me the correct query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MINUS` is a name for the "set difference" operator that is used only by Oracle.

SQL Server uses the (standard) name, `EXCEPT`, for this operator. Replacing the `MINUS` with `EXCEPT` will solve the issue:

```
SELECT Customer_Name
FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_No 
  IN
  (SELECT Customer_No FROM Customer
   EXCEPT
   SELECT Customer_No FROM DVD_Purchase
  ) ;
```

By the way, since the external query and the subquery reference the same table+column (`Customer . Customer_No`) you could use `NOT IN` without `EXCEPT`. Assuming that the columns involved (`Customer_No`) are not nullable, this is equivalent:

```
SELECT Customer_Name
FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_No 
  NOT IN
  (SELECT Customer_No FROM DVD_Purchase
  ) ;
```